# Removal of Macintosh HD

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons

Decided to give dual booting a try (OS X and Ubuntu) however the Macintosh HD icon honestly irritates me.

How can I remove this so it does not occur at all (click for larger versions)?

[image: Nautilus showing the unwanted icon]

[image: Launcher with the unwanted icon]

Comment: To the down-voter; mind telling me why?

Comment: Check these...
short answer: put noauto on the drive on the fstab
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1803779

Comment: Honestly, I read all that and still did not understand.

Comment: fstab is the place where the systems knows what's for the system to mount.

Comment: automount feature ends automounting this location. You have to manually tell you don't want it to mount.

Comment: unless you want to delete the OS X partition. Which is different.

Comment: Ahh thanks for explaining - the link provided does not seem to be helping much what should I follow?

Comment: Nono I want to dual boot them

Comment: You can try this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

Comment: This tutorial mounts a particular partition so how is this related to removing the appearence of the OS X partition? I am confused

Comment: just try this shortcut: {sudo gedit /etc/fstab} find the partition UUID

Comment: And add: "UUID=2ed003df-e129-38a6-b15a-10f1d86cf278 none none uid=0,owner,noauto 0 0" without quotes

Comment: I found the partition UUID. When you say add "UUID=.." where does this go? Instead of the found UUID? Also why do you suddenly write in Spanish ahaha?

Comment: be careful not to point the wrong UUID, or it will break your linux.

Comment: I really didn't give a good exemple... It IS NOT /dev/sda1 you have to find where your Macintosh partition is

Comment: I added a new solution, you can see what the file looks like... just save it after your're sure about the UUID

Comment: Sorry about the "spanish" I am from brazil, I was thinking in portuguese.

Answer (score -1):

Fast method (be sure about the UUID):

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID={} /               ext4     defaults,subvol=@ 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID={}  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=3dfc046ght43-2e3-40bc-81c8-23e84e820450 /home           ext4   defaults,subvol=@home 0       2



UUID=2ed003df-e139-48a6-b15a-25378925789 none   none uid=0,owner,noauto 0 0

#This last line has been added by you. Just subst it with you Macintosh HD partition UUID.
```

Comment: Which UUID is it?: http://pastebin.com/4EYX24pX - Assuming it is "50bed008-d67a-34b4-b2bb-9186d33e6189"

Comment: I see you have /dev/sda2: UUID="50bed008-d67a-34b4-b2bb-9186d33e6189" LABEL="Macintosh HD" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTLABEL="Macintosh HD" PARTUUID="00003d05-5081-0000-e40f-0000222a0000"

Comment: you have to add that line and delete this

Comment: I did on my mac and it worked

Comment: even no need to boot